# Gmail forwarding filter not working as intended

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, email-forwarding

I've created an email filter in my Gmail account for forwarding emails coming under a particular label (say "marriage") to another email id. However, now all emails arriving in my inbox are forwarded to this new email without respecting the filter. What am I doing wrong here?

(I'm attaching the screenshots of the filter I created)

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Answer (score 1):

- change `Has the word: "label:Marriage"` to `Has the word: "Marriage"`
- tick the checkbox **Apply the label:**
- and select label **`Marriage`**